# Can I get temporary health insurance while moving to the US?

Tags: usa, insurance, netherlands, h1b-visas

Soon, I will be moving from the Netherlands to the US on an H1B visa. My new employer in the US provides health insurance as soon as my contract starts. However, I will arrive one week before the start of my contract. Can I get temporary health insurance in the meantime?

By law, as soon as I deregister as a resident of the Netherlands, my Dutch health insurance immediately expires. There will thus be a period where I have no regular insurance in either country.

I have looked into travel insurance, but it seems (I could be wrong) that travel insurance only covers the cost of emergencies, and further relies on your regular insurance (which I don't have).

I have also considered taking private insurance. However, these plans span at least one month, and I am not sure if it would be problematic to have overlapping insurance plans.

Comment: One option which might be worth looking into is delaying the moment you deregister in the Netherlands with a week. I guess that would mean you're still a normal Dutch resident for that week and you could rely on travel insurance.

Comment: Sadly this is not an option. The Netherlands require me to deregister in person, and all deregistrations are effective immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my brother purchased temporary insurance for himself and his family upon arrival the USA through this service. It was recommended by the company he came to work for:
https://www.insubuy.com/temporary-workers-insurance-eligibility/

Comment: the answer to the question!

Comment: This website in this answer was very clear, and I have applied for short term health  insurance for a month. The same was also proposed by @Pont. Thank you both!

Answer (score 7):

> However, these plans span at least one month, and I am not sure if it would be problematic to have overlapping insurance plans.

In my experience, this is not a problem. It just means that, if you do need to make a claim, you should disclose all your applicable policies to each insurer so that they can sort out between themselves who's covering what; the claims form will probably request this explicitly. (Overlapping policies would only become a problem if you tried to make multiple, separate claims for the same costs, which I'm fairly sure would qualify as fraud.) You can always ask the insurance company about this when buying the policy if you want explicit confirmation that it's OK.